# Android activitiy converted to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an application which works. Now I would like to modify it in order to use the **ViewPager**. I mean, I have defined a new activity and I want to swipe between activities using the **ViewPager**. In order to do this I have transformed the original activity into a fragment. This is the original (simplified) code

```
public class ListViewImagesActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<Fish> image_details = populateList();

    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
    final ItemListBaseAdapter ilba = new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details);
    lv1.setAdapter(ilba);

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Fish obj_itemDetails = (Fish) o;

            Intent intent = new Intent(ListViewImagesActivity.this, DisplayFishDetailActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

I've modified the code in the following way.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class ListViewImagesActivity extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstancesState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_fish_detail, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    ArrayList<Fish> image_details = populateList();

    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final ItemListBaseAdapter ilba = new ItemListBaseAdapter(getActivity(), image_details);
    lv1.setAdapter(ilba);

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Fish obj_itemDetails = (Fish) o;

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayFishDetailActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Now, the adapter **ItemListBaseAdapter** receives the context using **getActivity()** instead of using **this** (in fact I am not sure if this is correct). When running the application I am gettin a **Null Pointer Exception** at **lv1.setAdapter(ilba)**.

Any hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `R.id.pager` the id for the ListView?

Comment: No, it is the id from the main.xml but changing it to the id of the ListView the result is the same, i.e. NPE

Comment: Clean your project, double check that `R.layout.activity_display_fish_detail` contains a `ListView` that has a proper id, and that you're accessing that same id when you're doing `findViewById()` and attach your full stack trace.

Comment: Well, the problem was that. A wrong Id. Cleaning and changing to the right Id was the solution. Thanks A--C!